# New installation: Win10 / Ubuntu Studio 16.04 dual boot and multiple partitions

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation

I'm in my 40's and heard the words Linux for years without ever looking into it.  So here I am as green as grass, excited about my new journey.

For 2 days straight I've been going around in circles trying to understand installation.  So, without further a do, I'll put my questions out here.

This is a new machine with clean installation of Win 10 on a **120 gb ssd m.2.  ASUS z170p mobo, 16gb 2400 DDR4 RAM.  i7 6700.**

Also have my  1TB SATA HDD  with Win 7 installed on it  **(I didn't want to delete it till I knew Win 10 was ok-this drive is partitioned with hundreds of gb's of data on, so simply removing the partition isn't possible; is it ?)**

I have downloaded Ubuntu Studio 16.04 and put it on a 64gb USB 3.0 drive  and plugged into a USB 3.0 port.  I've managed to work out how to change bios etc...

So, where am I now ?  I can Live boot to Studio.  I can also live boot directly to install.  My problem is what to do next.  It's taken me a full day to figure out why my interface is different to every single other video installation out out there. (actually I still don't know why my color scheme is different.  Mine is Grey while every other with  I've seen is burgundy/purple/brown? )  I had no option to press the `'+'` button in the Partition bit to change Primary, Logical, ext4 etc.  Turns out it was because I created a New Volume and formatted in Windows, instead of leaving it.

- What I would really appreciate is a full on rundown to get this dual booted and installed along Win10 (until i know i can live without it) on my 120gb ssd.  I have already partitioned it down to 30GB for Win 10 leaving around 90GB for Ubuntu. However I may have too many Primary Partitions now!
- Latest problem was Unusable space after i created (`/`) partition.  I'll make matters worse if I go over everything so I'm not assuming I actually know anything from here on in.

Would one of you kind people be willing to walk me through this process?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

actually there are only 4 primary partitions that can be created for any hdd (because of this u have unused space).

Now,take full backup(i know its hard but this will save you alot) then "clean"(windows command) it so that you can create primary partitions where you can dual boot, first windows then ubuntu.

One more thing to notice here is if your machine has two drive then one will be the primary drive and there you should install(/) of ubuntu (i.e. grub boot loader replaces windows) helps you in showing boot menu.

Comment: Thanks Sai.

I think I have over complicated my problem here.  I should start again and simply ask "How to install Ubuntu Studio 16.04 from a Live USB into a Dual Boot with Windows 10 already on my SSD.

I'm a total novice really so i need a thorough instruction from start to finish.  Can you point me to a tutorial?